# Radiofrequency attenuation in cold plasma

Tags: plasma-physics, radio-frequency

The missile plume can be considered a cold plasma. If a radio signal passes across the plume it's attenuated. Obviously the attenuation depends on the frequency of the signal. Where can I find some information about the behaviour of the RF across the cold plasma? Thanks

Comment: It isn't really related to "cold plasma". The attenuation of RF signals by rocket exhaust is due to free electrons in the plume, which are formed primarily by ionization of sodium and potassium or alkali metals. Sodium and potassium are present as
contaminants usually ammonium perchlorate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at:

[A Simple Method for Predicting RF Attenuation Through a Rocket Exhaust Plume](http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?AD=ADA443181&sa=U&ei=4c4yU_GyDOPksASIvIHQAw&ved=0CBsQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNFMamQvXTJcx2Q01j4l9aaOAA0KSQ)

and

[Radio Propagation through Rocket Exhaust Jets](http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/reports/arc/cp/0764.pdf)